LT6268-10 Opamp Oscillation and Offset
Below is my Photodiode-OpAmp circuit that is configured as Transimpedance Amplifier.

When I put both inverting and non inverting into ground, no signal is coming out. However when I connect Photodiode an oscillation with an offset around 1.5V is seen.

I simulated the same circuit on LTSpice without an issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Is the output driving anything? What does your PCB layout look like?

@JohnD Output directly goes into 50 Ohm terminated Oscilloscope. The circuit is on breadboard

A 500 MHz GBW op-amp on a breadboard can be a challenge due to many extra parasitics.

It's actually 4 GHz GBW. I'll give it a try on PCB then

Ah, right, even harder to breadboard.

"What am I doing wrong here?" - breadboarding.

Your simulation does not include the capacitance of the PD at 0V bias!

@SpehroPefhany sorry. capacitance of pd is around 700pF. It's an organic photodiode

You definitely need supply bypass capacitors right at the chip power pins.

@SpehroPefhany is that the reason why it's shorting?

I don't know about shorting, but it could well be helping it oscillate.

The "10" part of the "LTC6268-10" means it isn't stable for gains less than 10 and this means you have to be very careful when using it as a transimpedance amplifier. The capacitance of the photodiode has to be at least ten times higher in value than C2 (10 pF) or it will turn into an oscillator as stated in the data sheet: -
Since LTC6268-10 is a decompensated op amp with gainof-10 stable,
it requires that CIN/CF ≥ 10.

You also appear to be using breadboard and, that will never do for this type of device.

thanks Andy. I have printed the circuit on pcb accordingly as shown above however as soon as I connect output to Oscilloscope, Vc (-) is short circuiting. can you guide me on this please? thanks

@LifeIsBeatiful this question is largely unconnected with the original problem. You should ask this question in a new post. The benefit is that it opens up the floor to everyone rather than having this question targeted at only me so, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
